# How to implement the "i" (iteration) within the body() that contains an array when running RestAssured based Testing

Tags: java, rest

I was wondering how would you implement `"i"(iteration)` within the body() that contains an array when running RestAssured based Testing.I have a code below and as you can see `"body("Data[i].name" .... is not acceptable since I have "i"` within the quotes. Is there a way to implement "i" so it is recognized properly?

```
@Test
public void getContentTest1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        RestAuth auth = new RestAuth();
        auth.authAdmin()
            .parameters(
                "a", 0 ,
                "b", 3
                       )
            .expect().statusCode(200)
            .body("Data[i].name",containsString("Test") )
            .get(myURL);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is a good practice to implement iterations in testing methods, but why don't you try something like:

```
    public void getContentTest1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String dataName = "Data[" + i + "].name";
            RestAuth auth = new RestAuth();
            auth.authAdmin()
                .parameters(
                    "a", 0 ,
                    "b", 3
                 )
            .expect().statusCode(200)
            .body(dataName,containsString("Test") )
            .get(myURL);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer, go with it